# Vue.js does not work table filter single field

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I do CRM for the site. It is necessary that when you click on the corresponding button of the area, the table is filtered by this area. It seems everything is written correctly, but when you click on the button, nothing happens. States are loaded correctly on buttons. Data is taken from JSON.
Code:

```
    {% extends 'sycatalog/sy_profile.html' %}

{% block data %}
<div id="crm-app">
    <div class="managers">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="manager in managers">{% verbatim %}{{ manager.name_raw }}{% endverbatim %}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    #кнопка, которая должна фильтровать таблицу
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" :class="{active:state==selectedState}" v-for="state in states" @click="stateFilter(state)">
        {% verbatim %}{{ state.abbr }}{% endverbatim %}
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" @click="stateFilter('')">Сбросить</button>

    <v-server-table ref="table" url="/crm/customeroffice/" :columns="columns" :options="options">
    </v-server-table>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-tables-2@2.0.23/dist/vue-tables.js"></script>
<script>
    Vue.config.devtools = true;
    Vue.use(VueTables);

    const ServerTable = VueTables.ServerTable;
    const Event = VueTables.Event;

    Vue.use(ServerTable);
    new Vue({
        el: "#crm-app",
        methods: {
            stateFilter: function(state) { 
                let url = '/crm/customeroffice/'
                let params = {'state': state.id};                
                this.selectedState = state;

                axios.get(url, {
                    params: params
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.data = response.data.results;
                    this.$refs.table.refresh();
                }).catch( error => { console.log(error); })
                .finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
            },
            getManagers: function () { 
                let url = '/crm/crmuser/';
                let data = {'type': 'responsibles'};

                axios.get(url, {
                    params: data
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.managers = response.data.results;
                }).catch( error => { console.log(error); })
                .finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
            },
            getStates: function () { 
                let url = '/crm/state/';

                axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                    this.states = response.data.results;
                }).catch( error => { console.log(error); })
                .finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.getManagers();
            this.getStates();
        },
        data: {
            // filterByColumn: true,
            columns: ['id', 'customer', 'state'],
            // editableColumns:['name'],
            // sortable: ['sap', 'name'],
            // filterable: ['sap', 'name'],
            data: [],
            states: [],
            selectedState: '',
            managers: [],
            options: {
                requestFunction(data) {
                    return axios.get(this.url, {
                        params: data
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                        this.dispatch('error', e);
                    }).finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
                },
                responseAdapter(resp) {
                    var data = this.getResponseData(resp);
                    return {data: data.results, count: data.count}
                },
            }
        }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you're not using the `data` property (filtered states) anywhere in the template. Maybe you forgot to pass it to the `<v-server-table>` component?

Comment: @blex I still have little experience, tell me please what should I put in the `data`?

Comment: When you click on a filter button, you call the `stateFilter` method. That method (after fetching the data) is doing `this.data = ...`. So if everything is right, your data should already be alright. The problem is that you are then not using it anywhere. I suppose that your `<v-server-table>` component is the one where you want to use that data.

Comment: But  I just looked at the [documentation](https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/server-table), and it looks like `v-server-table` takes data from a URL, not a prop as you are trying to. Try replacing it with `v-client-table`, and setting `:data="data"` on it. Everything is [explained here](https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/client-table)

Comment: @blex so does not even display the table...

Comment: @blex I see that the filter doesn't work correct, I think that is the problem... The table is reloading (I see it in inspector, it is not refresh) and the data still the same